# MS Access database with no relations

Tags: database, data-migration

Can anyone recommend a tool or suggest the approach when dealing with MS Access database with no relationships between tables?

As part of data migration project I am creating data mapping definition rules but it becomes more and more difficult and time consuming to correctly identify source tables/fields for extraction.

I have many tables with the same data appearing in different places. Furthermore, as there were no validation rules when data was input, many entries contain spelling errors or generally do not match expected data type. Most of the tables however already have the keys (primary & foreign) created.

I am looking for a quick solution to rebuild the database (*.mdb), ideally with a use of some software which could identify all potential data issues, suggest corrections, allow for adjustments and finally left off with fully relational database where the data can easily be identified and not scattered all over the place. 
I have some general knowledge of databases and SQL but didn't use Access much before so I'm trying to save myself some of the time. And - if it matters - I don't care about database performance at all... Only the data itself. I will be extracting it to *.csv files later anyway...

Comments, suggestions and/or other considerations will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

J.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any software that will analyze an Access database and use some kind of artificial intelligence to generate a new database with good data and strong relationships.

My recommendation though is to export all the data into SQL Server (or even MySQL) and then work with it there. It's much easier to manipulate the data with a real query language instead of trying to scrub data in Access.

You can do mass updates, comparisons, joins, etc. with SQL Server. You can query the schema easily (write queries to see if a field appears in a table), change schemas/table definitions with code, etc.

Then once you're done you can use jobs (SSIS) to export the data to CSV.

(You can download SQL Express if you don't have/can't afford SQL Server.)

Comment: Thanks for response! Due to my serious time restrictions I am trying to avoid the hassle of exposing myself to such systems. And I guess all the processes you mentioned can be also be done in Access (well, at least those in scope of this task). In relation to software I would accept one without A.I. I don't expect it to decide what data goes in or out. But I would like it to tell me what data does not fit the pattern, or what data is likely to be invalid (based for example on their number compared to number of other items, or some other statistical function).
My main problem is the TIME!!!

Comment: BTW, to extract data from Access to csv I have used a Total Commander plug-in "ADO_DS" from 2006;) Did the job;)

Regards,
J.

Comment: Sorry I don't know of a data analysis tool for Access.  =(  Redgate is awesome for SQL Server, but I don't know what can be done with Access.  Maybe consider connecting to Access with ODBC and search for tools that can do analysis via ODBC?